# Opening an inner activity from the notification bar in android

Tags: android, navigation, android-activity

My application has three activities. Activity A calls Activity B and Activity B calls Activity C.

The back key would navigate the stack backwards C->B->A.

When I start the application from the notification bar I want to send the user to C but want to maintain the navigation pattern mentioned above, i.e. pressing back key should open activity B and pressing back key again should open activity A.

Any ideas on how to go about handling this

Comment: Android env supports this kind of behavior "out of the box" - no need to implement anything.

Comment: sorry may be the question is not clear. In the normal scenario where Activity A launches B and B launches C, I understand it works. But from the notification bar when I click the notification I want user to be taken directly Activity C. But I still want the on pressing the back key to open Activity B and so on. If I have not created or started activities A or B how would this work?

Comment: @gaurav Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need to `override back key` press in all activity..

```
onBackPressed()
{
 // make intent and call previous activity.
 // and finish this.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Soni's answer. You need to put the following code in the Activity class

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        //onCreate stuff
    }
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent backIntent=new Intent(this,PrevActivity.class);
        startActivity(backIntent);
    }
}
```

where PrevActivity.class is the name of the `Activity` class which needs to be launched on pressing back key. You need to put this code into every Activity, putting their previous class. Thus if the Flow is A>B>C, then Activity B has to put A.class in the intent and Activity C has to put B.class.

Comment: Yeah this works. I just had to extra flags such as FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to make sure that their is only one instance of the parent activity.